# How to summarize rows

Tags: sql, sum, rows

I have the below code (part of a much bigger code) which is used in a view.
It should sum up rows. However instead of 1 row it gives 4 rows summarizing the rows as it goes.
How do I get it to give only the final summary row?

It gives the following output:

```
PayPeriodID ADP_ID  EmpName CostString  Location    CostCenter  TotalPercentWorked  TotalHoursWorked    D8000   ModifiedBy
2117    002921  Richardson, Gerald  004-001 004 001 3.5114  3.09    61.1423 Non-Credible
2117    002921  Richardson, Gerald  048-001 048 001 0.2044  18.00   1152.3593   Credible
2117    002921  Richardson, Gerald  048-001 048 001 0.7424  65.32   1152.3593   Credible
2117    002921  Richardson, Gerald  048-001 048 001 0.7536  66.32   1152.3593   Credible
2117    002921  Richardson, Gerald  048-001 048 001 0.9468  83.32   1152.3593   Credible
2117    002921  Richardson, Gerald  048-013 048 013 0.3031  26.67   527.7729    Credible
```

Instead of:

```
PayPeriodID ADP_ID  EmpName CostString  Location    CostCenter  TotalPercentWorked  TotalHoursWorked    D8000   ModifiedBy
2117    002921  Richardson, Gerald  004-001 004 001 3.5114  3.09    61.1423 Non-Credible
2117    002921  Richardson, Gerald  048-001 048 001 0.9468  83.32   1152.3593   Credible
2117    002921  Richardson, Gerald  048-013 048 013 0.3031  26.67   527.7729    Credible
```

```
    SELECT        
        Data8000.PayPeriodID
        , Data8000.ADP_ID
        , Data8000.EmpName
        , Data8000.CostString
        , Data8000.Location
        , Data8000.CostCenter
        , Data8000.TotalPercentWorked
        , Data8000.TotalHoursWorked
        , Data8000.ExpAmt AS D8000
        , Data8000.ModifiedBy
    FROM     --Why is this a subquery?       
        (
            SELECT 
                AETCC.PayPeriodID
                , EI.ADP_ID
                , EI.LastName + ', ' + EI.FirstName AS EmpName
                , AETCC.LocationNum + '-' + AETCC.CostCenterNum AS CostString
                , AETCC.LocationNum AS Location
                , AETCC.CostCenterNum AS CostCenter
                , SUM(AD.TotalHoursWorked) as TotalHoursWorked 
                , SUM(AD.TotalPercentWorked) as TotalPercentWorked
                , SUM(AETCC.ExpenseAmount) AS ExpAmt, AETCC.ModifiedBy
            FROM dbo.AllocatedExpenseToCostCenter AS AETCC 
            INNER JOIN dbo.AllocationData AS AD 
                ON AETCC.ADP_ID = AD.ADP_ID 
                AND AETCC.CostCenterNum = AD.CostCenterNum 
                AND AETCC.LocationNum = AD.LocationNum 
                AND AETCC.PayPeriodID = AD.PayPeriodID 
                AND AETCC.ModifiedBy = AD.CreatedBy 
            INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeeInformation AS EI ON AETCC.ADP_ID = EI.ADP_ID
            WHERE        
                AETCC.ExpenseAccount = '8000'
                AND AETCC.ADP_ID = '002921' 
                AND AETCC.PayPeriodID = 2117
            GROUP BY 
                EI.ADP_ID
                , EI.FirstName
                , EI.LastName
                , AETCC.LocationNum
                , AETCC.CostCenterNum
                , AD.TotalPercentWorked
                , AD.TotalHoursWorked
                , AETCC.PayPeriodID
                , AETCC.ModifiedBy
                , AD.CreatedBy
        ) 
    AS Data8000
```

Comment: I havent really looked at your code but the issues is youre grouping by CostCode and they all have different values. Without really looking at it further I would suspect that is your issue

Comment: If your intent is to pull max cost center, then you should MAX() it up :)

Comment: CostCenter with value `048-001 048 001` is mentioned 2 times in the first query because you are also grouping on `CostCenterNum`, and there are 2 different values for that item with that CostCenter.

Comment: `group by` groups by (surprisingly) the specified columns. Your results are at this level of details. To aggregate it further you need to remove some columns from the `group by`

Comment: But if I remove items from the group by then it gives the following error: Column 'dbo.AllocatedExpenseToCostCenter.PayPeriodID' (or whatever column i remove) is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. And I need the column in the output!

Comment: I think my problem is the fact that AETCC and AD tables both have 4 records each for 048 001 which match on the 5 criteria for the inner join (INNER JOIN bo.AllocationData AS AD 
                ON AETCC.ADP_ID = AD.ADP_ID 
                AND AETCC.CostCenterNum = AD.CostCenterNum 
                AND AETCC.LocationNum = AD.LocationNum 
                AND AETCC.PayPeriodID = AD.PayPeriodID 
                AND AETCC.ModifiedBy = AD.CreatedBy). Perhaps I need some sort of union instead

Comment: I have 2 tables: AllocationData as AD which records hours (TotalHoursWorked) and percentage or work (TotalPercentWorked) and AllocatedExpenseToCostCenter as AETCC which records Expenses. What I need is to combine these 2 tables into 1 output that gives me the sums of all Hours, Percentage of work, and Expense Amount by location and cost center.  So for 048 001 there are 4 total records in each of AETCC and AD tables and the total sums would be Total Hours 58.24, Total Percent 0.6618, and total Expenses would be $1741.27

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        
        Data8000.PayPeriodID
        , Data8000.ADP_ID
        , Data8000.EmpName
        , Data8000.CostString
        , Data8000.Location
        , Data8000.CostCenter
        , Data8000.TotalPercentWorked
        , Data8000.TotalHoursWorked
        , Data8000.ExpAmt AS D8000
        , Data8000.ModifiedBy
    FROM     --Why is this a subquery?       
        (
            SELECT 
                AETCC.PayPeriodID
                , EI.ADP_ID
                , EI.LastName + ', ' + EI.FirstName AS EmpName
                , AETCC.LocationNum + '-' + AETCC.CostCenterNum AS CostString
                , AETCC.LocationNum AS Location
                , AETCC.CostCenterNum AS CostCenter
                , SUM(AD.TotalHoursWorked) as TotalHoursWorked 
                , SUM(AD.TotalPercentWorked) as TotalPercentWorked
                , SUM(AETCC.ExpenseAmount) AS ExpAmt, AETCC.ModifiedBy
            FROM dbo.AllocatedExpenseToCostCenter AS AETCC 
            INNER JOIN dbo.AllocationData AS AD 
                ON AETCC.ADP_ID = AD.ADP_ID 
                AND AETCC.CostCenterNum = AD.CostCenterNum 
                AND AETCC.LocationNum = AD.LocationNum 
                AND AETCC.PayPeriodID = AD.PayPeriodID 
                AND AETCC.ModifiedBy = AD.CreatedBy 
            INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeeInformation AS EI ON AETCC.ADP_ID = EI.ADP_ID
            WHERE        
                AETCC.ExpenseAccount = '8000'
                AND AETCC.ADP_ID = '002921' 
                AND AETCC.PayPeriodID = 2117
            GROUP BY 
                EI.ADP_ID
                , EI.FirstName
                , EI.LastName
                ,CostCenterNum 
                , AETCC.LocationNum
        ) 
    AS Data8000
```